# Deleted ShipperHQ module causing error in "All Customers" section of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, database, error, sql

I'm currently trying to build a Magento 2 site to replace an existing Magento 1 site. As we currently use the MatrixRates Module we decided to give ShipperHQ a try but ultimately decided against using it.

My intial installation of ShipperHQ occured some time ago but I believe that we initially tried to install this by Zip. Having been told that this was not ideal I reinstalled the ShipperHQ module using composer as advised and tried to remove it using the instructions provided (via composer).

The instructions are here:

https://docs.shipperhq.com/uninstalling-the-magento-extension/#How_to_Uninstall_the_ShipperHQ_Extension_for_Magento_2

It stated that module logger was not required by composer but aside from that everything seemed to go OK.

In the admin section of the site. I tried to look at the "All customers" page in the customers section and received the following error:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 900078875686

The var reports provided the following report.

> {"0":"Class
>   ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AddressType
>   does not exist","1":"#0
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('ShipperHQ\\Shipp...')\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('ShipperHQ\\Shipp...')\n#2
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(100):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('ShipperHQ\\Shipp...')\n#3
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('ShipperHQ\\Shipp...',
>   Array)\n#4
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('ShipperHQ\\Shipp...',
>   Array)\n#5
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php(590):
>   Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('ShipperHQ\\Shipp...')\n#6
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource()\n#7
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor->___callParent('getSource',
>   Array)\n#8
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/Mirasvit/Rewards/Plugin/Customer/Model/AttributePlugin.php(41):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()\n#9
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Mirasvit\Rewards\Plugin\Customer\Model\AttributePlugin->aroundGetSource(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure))\n#10
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()\n#11
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Attribute/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getSource',
>   Array, NULL)\n#12
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php(68):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor->getSource()\n#13
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php(77):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Interceptor))\n#14
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php(109):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\AddressMetadata->getAttributeMetadata('destination_typ...')\n#15
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CachedMetadata.php(85):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\AddressMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()\n#16
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/AttributeRepository.php(85):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CachedMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()\n#17
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php(102):
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository->getList()\n#18
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(159):
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns->prepare()\n#19
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(156):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))\n#20
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(137):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))\n#21
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(97):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure),
>   'customer_listin...', Array,
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))\n#22
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(80):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))\n#23
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(344):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))\n#24
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()\n#25
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()\n#26
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()\n#27
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()\n#28
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()\n#29
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(876):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()\n#30
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')\n#31
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')\n#32
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php(26):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Custome...')\n#33
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute()\n#34
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#35
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#36
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#37
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#38
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#39
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#40
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#41
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#42
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#43
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#44 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#45
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/m2e/ebay-amazon-magento2/Plugin/AbstractPlugin.php(34):
>   call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)\n#46
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/m2e/ebay-amazon-magento2/Plugin/HealthStatus/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(42):
>   Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\AbstractPlugin->execute('dispatch',
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Array)\n#47
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\HealthStatus\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#48
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#49
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#50
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#51
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#52
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#53
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#54
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#55
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.magentotwo.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#56
>   {main}","url":"/admin_mysite/customer/index/index/key/e8c16f8c6e10f3b3aaacccb164e4fdfc841c42429b2edabbe24a0933fda6a954/","script_name":"/index.php"}

I can't see the AddressType in the EAV_attributes table in my database, have I missed something that I should have deleted?

Can anyone enlighten me regarging how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto the database and open the table **eav_attribute** and search the below **attribute_code** and delete those from that table:

```
shipperhq_shipping_group
shipperhq_warehouse
shipperhq_shipping_fee
shipperhq_handling_fee
shipperhq_volume_weight
shipperhq_declared_value
shipperhq_dim_group
shipperhq_poss_boxes
shipperhq_malleable_product
shipperhq_master_boxes
shipperhq_availability_date
destination_type
freight_class
shipperhq_nmfc_class
must_ship_freight
shipperhq_nmfc_sub
```

Above attributes are created from **ShipperHQ** extension. Flush the cache and test again.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That got it! Turns out I'd missed "destination_type", that was still in there! 

Thank you so much, that really helped!

Comment: I had the same thing happen, this worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much Sukumar, your answer totally saved me a lot of time. I have put it in a convenient SQL request:

> DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` IN (
>   'shipperhq_shipping_group', 'shipperhq_warehouse',
>   'shipperhq_shipping_fee', 'shipperhq_handling_fee',
>   'shipperhq_volume_weight', 'shipperhq_declared_value',
>   'shipperhq_dim_group', 'shipperhq_poss_boxes',
>   'shipperhq_malleable_product', 'shipperhq_master_boxes',
>   'shipperhq_availability_date', 'destination_type', 'freight_class',
>   'shipperhq_nmfc_class', 'must_ship_freight', 'shipperhq_nmfc_sub' )